# Clear Laravel's orderBy

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a generic function which gives me generic querysets, something like:

```
class Model extends Eloquent {
  public static function get_queryset(){
    $queryset = self::where('foo','=','bar');
    // Do tons of stuff with the query and then...
    return $queryset->orderBy('somefield');
  }
}
```

This function is used everywhere my project, but in a specific point I need to use this queryset but **changing** the ORDER BY, much like this:

```
public static function get_specific_field(){
  return self::get_queryset()->select('singlefield')->orderBy('singlefield');
}
```

If I run this code, the ORDER BY will just append onto the previous and generate an invalid query, since the "somefield" is not on the SELECTed fields. i.e.:

```
SELECT singlefield FROM table ORDER BY somefield ASC, singlefield ASC
```

How do I clear the orderBy so I can just reuse querysets?

Answer (score 47):

I agree there should be a `clearOrderBy()` method added to the query builder. However because the registry of orderbys is a public property on `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` you actually can clear it yourself today. The trick is getting access to the base query object:

```
$query = YourModel::where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at','desc');
// ... lots of other code, something needs to reset the order by ...
$query->getQuery()->orders = null;
$query->orderBy('other_column', 'desc');
```

At other times, for example when manipulating a relation query, you need to get to access the base query (`Illuminate\Database\Query\Query`). So for example:

```
$query = YourModel::find(1)->load('children', function ($query) {
    $query->getBaseQuery()->orders = null;
});
```

Thats it. I plan to submit a PR for a `clearOrderBy()` as well.

Comment: @jpshroeder did you ever do a PR for `clearOrderBy()`?

Comment: In Laravel 7+ (at least through 10) there is a reorder() method to clear existing order by clauses.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#removing-existing-orderings

Answer (score 12):

In Laravel 7, there's now a method to remove the orders from the query builder ([#32186](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32186)):

```
public static function get_specific_field(){
    return self::get_queryset()->select('singlefield')->reorder('singlefield');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since this is a pretty old question and probably most of you have already upgraded to Laravel 7 and above, you can use the built-in `reorder()` method as @halloei mentions ([#32186](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32186)).

However, if you are stuck with Laravel bellow version 7, you can make a macro using the idea from the PR. Then you can use `reorder()` as you would with Laravel 7. Just register that in the `AppServiceProvider@boot`.

```
\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::macro('reorder', function ($column = null, $direction = 'asc') {
   $this->orders = null;
   $this->unionOrders = null;
   $this->bindings['order'] = [];
   $this->bindings['unionOrder'] = [];

   if ($column) {
      return $this->orderBy($column, $direction);
   }

   return $this;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not "genericise" your queryset?

```
class Model extends Eloquent {
  public static function get_queryset($orderBy = 'somefield'){
    $queryset = self::where('foo','=','bar');
    // Do tons of stuff with the query and then...
    return $queryset->orderBy($orderBy);
  }
}
```

Then you can use

```
public static function get_specific_field(){
  return self::get_queryset('singlefield')->select('singlefield');
}
```

Comment: It's not that I can't do this, but still, there should be a way to clear what's being ordered

Comment: Why "should" there be a way? The Eloquent query builder is all about building queries, not about changing existing queries.... and the simple answer is that there isn't any method defined to modify the `$orders` array in the query builder..... although `$orders` is a public property of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` so you have read/write access to the property value

Comment: The problem with not allowing to change things in the queryset is that it then becomes a sponge, you can just add stuff into it, but not work with the same object to get different responses, it becomes "less" object oriented. The maintenance becomes harder, since in the future you may need to update tons of code to just add a new feature

Comment: Thank you about the $orders property, I probably missed it on the documentation, this might as well be enough.

Comment: Well you've created that problem for yourself (Eloquent hasn't done it for you) by enforcing an orderBy clause in your `get_queryset()` method without allowing yourself to override or change it

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution , tiny package you can use it by simply calling `->clearOrdersBy()`
https://github.com/phpfalcon/laravel-clear-orders-by

Answer (score 2):

Off the back of @halloei answer which can be construed as a little unclear, you can simply do the below which will clear all existing orders, at the same time as applying new orders.

```php
// get all users and sort by ID
$builder = User::query()->orderBy('id');

// now scrap that order and sort by email
$builder->reorder('email');
```