# Laravel - Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vw_winning_report.id'

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to generate a report from five tables by combining them as Mysql views using the query below:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_winning_report AS
 SELECT             
            id as tid,
            msisdn,
            game_code,
            game_name,
            prize,
            total_per_day,
            user_channel,
            created_at
       FROM trivial_winners
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
            id as tid,
            msisdn,
            game_code,
            game_name,
            prize,
            total_per_day,
            user_channel,
            created_at         
       FROM predict_and_win
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
            id as tid,
            msisdn,
            game_code,
            game_name,
            prize,
            total_per_day,
            user_channel,
            created_at        
       FROM party_with_bbn
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
            id as tid,
            msisdn,
            game_code,
            game_name,
            prize,
            total_per_day,
            user_channel,
            created_at         
       FROM happy_hour
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
            id as tid,
            msisdn,
            game_code,
            game_name,
            prize,
            total_per_day,
            user_channel,
            created_at          
       FROM grand_price
```

Then I created a model class in Laravel name WinningReport.

```
class WinningReport extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'vw_winning_report';

 protected $fillable = [
  'tid',
  'msisdn',
  'game_code',
  'game_name',
  'prize',
  'total_per_day',
  'user_channel',
  'created_at'
 ];       
}
```

Then the Controller for the index page and the export function. exportwinningreport is for export while winningreportReport(Request $request) is for the index page.

```
    public function winningreportReport(Request $request)
{
    $data['title'] = 'Winning Report';

    $winners = DB::table('vw_winning_report')
    ->select(
       'msisdn', 
       'game_code',
       'game_name',
       DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as created_date')
  )               
 ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC'); 

    $render=[];       
    if(isset($request->msisdn))
    {
        $winners=$winners->where('msisdn','like','%'.$request->msisdn.'%');
        $render['msisdn']=$request->msisdn;
    }
    if(isset($request->game_code))
    {
        $winners=$winners->where('game_code',$request->game_code);
        $render['game_code']=$request->game_code;
    }               
    if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $winners=$winners->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date,$request->end_date]);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
    }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $winners=$winners->where('created_at',$request->start_date);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
    }         
    $winners= $winners->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    $winners= $winners->paginate(15);
    $winners= $winners->appends($render);
    $data['winners'] = $winners;

return view('report.winningreportReport',$data);        
}

public function exportwinningreport() 
{
    return Excel::download(new WinningreportExport, 'winningreport.xlsx');
}
```

Then for the Export when a submit button is clicked, we have:

```
class WinningreportExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{

use Exportable;
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
*/
public function query()
{
    return WinningReport::query()->select(
    DB::raw("DATE(created_at)"),
    'msisdn',
    'game_code',
    'game_name'
            );
}    

public function headings(): array
{
    return [
    'Date Created',
    'MSISDN',
    'Game Code',
    'Game Name',
    ];
}   

public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
            $cellRange = 'A1:D1'; // All headers
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(14);
        },

    ];
}       
}
```

The index view page is working perfectly, but when I clicked on the Export Submit button I got this error:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vw_winning_report.id' in 'order clause' (SQL: select DATE(created_at), `msisdn`, `game_code`, `game_name` from `vw_winning_report` order by `vw_winning_report`.`id` asc limit 1000 offset 0)

What is the cause of the problem and how do I resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: What if you change `WinningReport::query()->select(...)` to `WinningReport::select(...)`?

Comment: I did that but the problem still remains

Comment: I have idea, why there is an ORDER BY clause in the query. But you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869897/clear-laravels-orderby)

Comment: I mean "I have **no** idea .."

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I just added

> ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC');

to the query and it works.

Thanks everyone